# assigning value of an obect to another object in ios

Tags: ios

I have seen this statement in an ios tutorial.May i know what this statement means.
Is this means pointing the velue of sender object to another object s.

```
UISlider *s=(UISlider *)sender;
```

Can any one help me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's typecasting `sender` as a `UISlider*`. You're telling the compiler "Trust me, I know `sender` is a `UISlider*`". Once assigned to `s`, then you may use `s` as a `UISlider` without improved type checking (if `id`) and without warnings (if `sender` is an objc object of specified type). If it is not a `UISlider`, then your program may encounter errors at runtime.

Also note that `sender` is often associated to an object/control which performed an action, and is typically declared with a type `id`, e.g. `- (IBAction)performSomeAction:(id)sender`. In that case, `UISlider * s = (UISlider*)sender;` is redundant. I favor the simpler `UISlider * s = sender;`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, methods that take sender parameters name the type of `sender` as `id`. `id`'s are generic object pointers. The point of that code is to cast the type of sender into `UISlider*` so that you can call the methods of UISlider on it without generating compiler warnings.

Comment: @ Ryan Ballantyne Thanks dude.Can you suggest me amy useful tutorials for ios for a beginner like me

Comment: @AnazA I'd suggest you stay far away from iOS while you're a beginner. Start learning C properly first. In fact, this question has little to do with Objective-C and iOS, you could do this with 2 arbitrary C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's typecasting.
Here the sender is typecast-ed to type `UISlider`.

It's similar to `C` Syntax,

```
int x = (int)aValue;
```